# Command works in shell but not in a script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ls

I'm using the command `ls files/@(*.text|*.txt|*.xt)` to get all files that end with any of the patterns.

When I run it in the shell I get this result

```
$ ls files/@(*.text|*.txt|*.xt)
files/f1.text  files/f1.txt  files/f1.xt
```

When I create a bash script, it throws the error `ls: cannot access files/@(*.text|*.txt|*.xt): No such file or directory`

Here is a copy of my bash script

```
#!/bin/bash

ls files # this one works
ls files/@\(*.text\|*.txt\|*.xt\) # This doesn't work
```

full output when running the bash script

```
$ ./testScript.sh 
files/f1.text  files/f1.txt  files/f1.xt
ls: cannot access files/@(*.text|*.txt|*.xt): No such file or directory
```

Confirmed the shell is a bash shell

```bash
$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
```

I also tried:

- `ls files/@\(*.text|*.txt|*.xt\)` - throws `line 4: *.xt): command not found`
- `ls files/@(*.text|*.txt|*.xt)` - throws `line 4: syntax error near unexpected token` ('`
- running with `sh ./testScript.sh` - same error as original error.
- using `/files/@(*.text|*.txt|*.xt)` - no luck (same error as above in this list)

Comment: If you run `echo $SHELL` manually what is the output? Next, if you run `sh ./testScript.sh` do you still receive the same error? Finally can you update your ls command to `ls ./files/@(*.text|*.txt|*.xt)` (path updated) and let us know if the error is the same?

Comment: post the output of `shopt | grep extglob` both from the command line and within the script. `@(pattern-list)` only matches one of the patterns if `extglob` is set. There is also the caveat that if your script is started with a EUID or EGID that does not match the real UID or GID, then `$SHELLOPTS` and `$BASHOPTS` set in the parent are ignored.

Comment: Edited the question to add more information, thanks @PCDSandwichMan.

@DavidC.Rankin Running `shopt | grep extglob`

Result on terminal: `extglob         on`
Result from the script: `extglob         off`

Seems like that root causes the problem, need to figure out how to fix that

Comment: @PCDSandwichMan The value of $SHELL is completely unrelated. It does not indicate which shell is currently running, nor which shell would be run.

Answer (score 0):

You enable extglob in your script with `shopt -s extglob`.